# Notice: Undefined index: quantity

Tags: error, quantity, index, undefined

I am currently facing a problem with the below error and was hoping if someone could help.

```
Notice: Undefined index: quantity in /public_html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php on line 87
```

I have found solutions to other Undefined Index problems but not to mine.

This error happens on the product page when I edit certain products. Please note it only happens to a few products.

I've tried to go into the attribute settings, re-saving and then reindexing but this has not worked. I've had a look into the database and couldn't find anything that stands out as wrong.

Any helps is appreciated, I am also getting a **"Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state."** error when searching for some products but I believe these problems are related.

Screenshots below

Something went wrong https://pasteboard.co/Jhs7D2g.png
Undefined Index https://pasteboard.co/Jhs7JPU.png
Line 87 https://pasteboard.co/Jhs95Pm.png

Thanks